# A good JS library for housing electrical schematics

Tags: javascript, raphael, jointjs

Is there any javascript library available like, Raphaeljs or Jointjs but for showing/drawing electrical schematics. For instance want to make a JS/HTML page for showing the function of a transistor in a electronic diagram.

First i want to draw the diagram and then i want to show it to the user in a kind of read only way.

Is there a more suitable library for this or should i start modifying jointjs or raphael with custom figures.

Or should i just use images from omnigraffle and add add some buttons on top of it?

Comment: Read only? Just export from OmniGraffle and enjoy a beer.

Comment: I want the user to be able to click on a "electrical" switch... but i dont want the user to be able to rebuild the circuit "drag'n drop"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the schematics in JointJS, then open the graph in a `joint.dia.Paper` that has set `interactive: false` flag. This way you disable drag&drop but you can still react on clicks on the elements with: `paper.on('cell:pointerup', function(cellView, evt, x, y) { ... });`

Comment: Would you prefer this over JQuery+ JQuery-svg?

Comment: @DavidKarlsson my answer would be biased as I'm the lead dev behind JointJS. Though still I'd like to point out that JointJS is made for diagramming and so it makes a lot of sense to use it in this case.

Comment: @dave, I found a CDN for JointJS https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/jointjs. My question is, can it be used as only showing electrical schematics like abcjs for musical notes and 3dmoljs for molecules? I would like use it an a Hugo shortcode. Thank you for any comment and advice.